# It is redundant to wrap dialogs in using blocks?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the following code, are the using blocks redundant or are they necessay to fully release resources?

```
using (var dialog = new AboutBox())
    dialog.ShowDialog();

using (var form = new OptionForm())
    form.Show();
```

Comment: Your second example open a modeless form, so your code exit immediately and your form will be closed.

Comment: It's not totally out of the ordinary to do nothing and keep the Form around to ShowDialog() it again. A SearchFroms for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first example is not redundant.  You should always dispose of an `IDisposable` the moment you are done with it and in the case of a modal form this exactly accomplishes the goal.

The second example though will lead to errors.  The `Show` method returns immediately and the form continues to be displayed.  However the generated `using` code will immediately `Dispose` the form and cause it to go away.  The form should only be disposed once it's finished showing.

Comment: Minor addition for the OP: when using ShowDialog it explicitly does not dispose itself; when using Show, it explicitly does (when closed)

Comment: Is the Close() method of Form calling Dispose()? Because if it is the case, won't be the form already disposed once ShowDialog finishes? (either by a call to Close in the form or by a user click on the X)

Comment: @asmo see Marc's comment for that.

Comment: Seems like you foresaw my thoughts, Marc.